# What is the purpose of the second (Effect:Deny, Condition:Null) Statement of this S3 bucket policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Reading this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html) it give an example for forcing encryption on bucket:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "PutObjPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyIncorrectEncryptionHeader",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YourBucket/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YourBucket/*",
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the second condition actually doing and why is it necessary, to me, looks like I'd only need the first one? I don't understand what NULL is even doing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_Null),

> Use a Null condition operator to check if a condition key is present
>   at the time of authorization. In the policy statement, use either true
>   (the key doesn't exist — it is null) or false (the key exists and its
>   value is not null).

So in your example if the key s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption doesn't exist, it should be null to make the condition successful.

Answer (score 4):

The Null condition in the **condition block** evaluates to true if the `s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption key` value is `null`. This rule is checking for a missing header.

In the first rule in this policy, the encryption value is being compared. In order for this comparison to occur the header must be present. The second rule detects that the header is missing, thereby enforcing that an encryption selection occurs.

Summary:

The first rule checks the value of the encryption header.

The second rule checks if the header is present.

Comment: Hi John, are you sure? The first condition alone does block putObject with the SSE header absent.

Comment: Hi @jarmod With AWS policies I am never 100% sure. I wish that Amazon would offer a debugger or tracer for policies so that we could see the actual evaluations that occur and the results.

Comment: *"In order for this comparison to occur the header must be present."*  Intuitively, this would be right, but I suspect proper TLV logic doesn't apply to `StringNotEquals`.  A null "value" is not subject to an inequality comparison, so is technically neither equal to or not equal to any value, but I think IAM policies are not so strict, and the second statement is redundant.  Unfortunately, the IAM policy documentation is apparently silent on null value handling in inequality comparisons.

Comment: Did someone test this?

Answer (score 0):

Ours is a little different in that we have apps incapable of setting SSE and we also want to avoid custom KMS keys. By leveraging default bucket encryption this policy ensures either default bucket encryption or AES256 is employed for encryption at rest.

```
{
        "Sid": "Ensure encryption at rest",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "false"
            },
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
            }
        }
    }
```